# I can't get custom control's selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

Pager.xaml(View)

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      x:Class="Client.View.Pager">
    ...
    <ListBox x:Name="listBoxEntries"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListCollectionView}"
             BorderThickness="0"
             Margin="0"
             Style="{StaticResource common}"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource templateTableCategory}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedEntry, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding Path=Rows}"
                             Columns="{Binding Path=Columns}"
                             IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
    ...
</Grid>
```

Pager.xaml.cs(Behind code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Client.Model;
using Client.ViewModel;

namespace Client.View
{
    public partial class Pager
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedEntryProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedEntry", typeof(IPagableEntry), typeof(Pager));
        ...
        public IPagableEntry SelectedEntry
        {
            get { return (DataContext as PagerViewModel).SelectedEntry; }
            set { (DataContext as PagerViewModel).SelectedEntry = value; }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

PagerViewModel.cs

```
namespace Client.ViewModel
{
    public class PagerViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        ...

        IPagableEntry _selectedEntry;
        public IPagableEntry SelectedEntry
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedEntry;
            }

            set
            {
                _selectedEntry = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEntry");
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml(View)

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      x:Class="Client.View.MainPage"
      Style="{StaticResource common}">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainPageViewModel/>
    </Page.DataContext>
    ...

    <view:Pager x:Name="pagerTableCategories"
            Grid.Row="0"
            List="{Binding Path=PagerTableCategoriesItems}"
            Rows="{Binding Path=PagerTableCategoriesRows}"
            Columns="{Binding Path=PagerTableCategoriesColumns}"
            SelectedEntry="{Binding Path=SelectedTableCategory, Mode=TwoWay}">
    </view:Pager>
    ...
</Page>
```

MainPageViewModel.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Client.Model;

namespace Client.ViewModel
{
    public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        ...
        IPagableEntry _selectedTableCategory;

        public IPagableEntry SelectedTableCategory
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedTableCategory;
            }
            set
            {
                _selectedTableCategory = value;
                MessageBox.Show("Got it!");
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

I made a custom panel 'Pager' and that's ViewModel.
and I wanna show the pager in my MainPage.
I expect that I select an item, then MainPageViewModel's property SelectTableCategory will change, and an message box show up with string "Got it!"
But it doesn't works...
what's my problem?

ps. I am not very good at English.
I would appreciate your understanding.

Comment: Your `SelectedEntry` property should know **nothing** about your View Model. Therefore using the `DataContext` to return a property in your view model via the dependency property is certainly not the best method to achieve this. A custom dependency property should not need to depend on the `DataContext` being a particular view model type. **EDIT** A standard dependency property should solve this problem. Just type `propdp` -> Tab -> Tab and visual studio will provide you with one.

Answer (score 1):

Let's work from first principles.

You have a custom control called Pager, which is to be used like this

```
<view:Pager x:Name="pagerTableCategories"
        SelectedEntry="{Binding Path=SelectedTableCategory, Mode=TwoWay}">
</view:Pager>
```

See how SelectedEntry is assigned a binding? This tells us that Pager must implement SelectedEntry as a dependency property. How do we do this?

```
public class Pager
{
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PrePend.  
    //   This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedEntryProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedEntry", typeof(object), 
          typeof(Pager), 
          new PropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedEntryChanged));

    public object SelectedEntry
    {
         get { return GetValue(SelectedEntryProperty); }
         set { SetValue(SelectedEntryProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnSelectedEntryChanged(DependencyObject pager, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
    {
         // TODO set the SelectedItem in the ListBox
    }
}
```

Next you need to display the Pager. Your XAML looks ok. You should add an event handler on the ListBox to listen to selection changed event. This way, you can update `SelectedEntry` when that occurs.

```
public class Pager
{
    // continued...

    // *Updated*
    private listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SelectedEntry = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But, How can I set the item in the listbox? That method(OnSelectedEntryChanged) is static, but the listbox isn't so I can't access listbox in static method.

Comment: I did it like this:
(pager as Pager).listBoxEntries.SelectedItem = e.NewValue;

But SelectedTableCategory's set property in MainPageViewModel doesn't be called automatically yet...

Comment: Fixed bug in listBox_SelectionChanged